# Should I lubricate a BBS01 clutch?

Tags: electric-bike, commuting-bike

I am completing the rebuild of a BBS01 electric bike mid-drive motor from Bafung.  Would like to lubricate and protect every part properly before reassembly. Should I lubricate the clutch and if so with what lubricant?  I have read concerns about slippage in a lubricated clutch.  Thanks in advance!  [image: Assembled Clutch]  [image: Inner Clutch]  [image: Outer Clutch]

Comment: i would think a light grease would be sufficient but don't go off my word, curious to see what others say.

Comment: What you DON'T want to do is put a big blob of grease in the space between the pawls and the center rotor.  This would create suction that would prevent the pawls from quickly popping out as they move by each tooth in the outside ring.  And you don't want blobs of grease in the notches between teeth, as that will make the pawls slow to "settle".  You DO want a light coating of lubricant between the rounded end of the pawl  and the center rotor, so the pawl moves freely.  Basically some thin, fairly fluid grease or some sort of oil.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure I'd call that a clutch.... ;) More a freewheel.

I have done jobs like this in the past, and I found using a Lithium Grease (very thin, textured a bit like facial cream) works great, so long as you only line it on the teeth.
[image: TF2 Litium Grease in a tub.]

On the one I had, however, it had a seal which meant there was no way the grease could get out. Something important to note is that, if you DO have one of these with a seal on them, don't competely fill it with grease. Where you have moving parts, you want a void and a way for it to 'breathe', otherwise the seal will physically pop. You want more air than grease; Air is compressible, grease (classed as a liquid) is not.

If it's not sealed, only a very thin layer. It's purpose is to keep it lubricated and to keep the teeth themselves clean and not directly contacting metal-on-metal, a bad thing in an electric motor which moves very fast under heavy load. If you use too little, the gears will chew each other up, making what little grease there is turn into a grinding paste. Too much grease, and it'll start blurting out of the side, onto other vital, expensive components.

Good luck!

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The referenced grease is "White Lithium Grease" and I've only seen it in a spray can.    It smells like an engineering workshop.

Comment: Well, Actually, the stuff I use is 'TF2 Lithium Grease', it's a tub of the grease itself, not a spray, hehehehe. 
And yes, very much smells like an engineering workshop, hahaaha, the best smell to walk into early in the morning, if you ask me; Somewhat akin to the smell of a two-stroke at about 7AM. Oh, the heavenly, manly aroma of a two-stroke.... :P

Answer (score 2):

That's not a clutch. It's the same type of freewheel that's in most hubs. There is plenty of info available online about servicing them. I found this guide on Park's web site, which recommends grease. There's a link the stuff they make but there are many that will work just fine. http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/freehub-service